# Passing a returned value from a predicate to another predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

When running just a single predicate, the program properly handles the user input.

【Code】

```
main:-
    chooseusertype.

chooseusertype:-
    write('Log in as a merchant or customer?: '),
    read(X),
    format('Your log in type: ~w', [X]).
```

【The result of execution】

```
Log in as a merchant or customer?: customer.
Your log in type: customer
```

However, when I try to pass the input given within the chooseusertype predicate to the startas predicate

【Code】

```
main(-Usertype):-
    chooseusertype,
    startas(Usertype).

chooseusertype:-
    write('Log in as a merchant or customer?: '),
    read(X),
    format('Your log in type: ~w', [X]).

startas('merchant'):-
    write('Logged in as merchant'), nl,
    write('Any update on the shelves?').

startas('customer'):-
    write('Logged in as customer'), nl,
    write('Let us help you find the ingredients you want!').
```

【The result of execution】

```
false
```

It fails. I know that the syntax is not correct, but I don’t find any Prolog documentation well-written, and I’m stuck because of that. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `main` and `chooseusertype` like this, such taht `read/1` returns the choosen option:

```
main:-
    chooseusertype(Usertype),
    startas(Usertype).

chooseusertype(X):-
    write('Log in as a merchant or customer?: '),
    read(X),
    format('Your log in type: ~w', [X]).
```

From [SWI documentation](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read/1):

> `read(-Term)` Read the next Prolog term from the current input stream
>   and unify it with `Term`

Moreover, if you want to print an error message, you can do:

```
main:-
    chooseusertype(Usertype),
    ( startas(Usertype) -> 
        true; 
        format('~nUser type not recognised: ~w', [Usertype]),
        fail
    ).

?- main.
Log in as a merchant or customer?: asd.
Your log in type: asd
User type not recognised: asd
false.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's precisely the answer that I've been looking for :)